# Kitniyot for gerim?

Tags: minhag, conversion-to-judaism, kitniyos-semigrain-legume

How does a *ger* decide whether to follow Ashkenazic or Sephardic *minhagim*? In particular, can a *ger* eat *kitniyot* during Pesach?

Comment: Depends on which minhagim he follows to begin with. If he follows Ashkenazic minhagim in general why should he change to a Sephardic minhag (especially that of kitniyos?!) See here (related): http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22156/a-convert-taking-on-customs-of-ashkanazim-or-sephardim

Comment: Thanks for your comment and to @msh210 for pointing to the more complete discussion.