# Can a convert choose the Teimani (Yemenite) minhagim?

Tags: minhag, conversion-to-judaism, yemenite-temani

From what I know, Rabbi Ovadia Yosef (Teshuva Shu"T Yachaveh Das Chelek 5 Siman 33) writes that someone who converts in Eretz Yisrael must take on the Minhagim of the Sephardim. However, according to this option, could someone who converts outside of eretz Yisrael be choose the Teimani minhag?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya. Can you [edit] your question to make it less personal? We [try to avoid practical halachic questions](//meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1734). You might also want to see "[Why is it necessary to ask a rabbi?](//judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146)" for more info. We hope to see you around!

Comment: The principle of "having to choose" your minhagim is... complicated, to say the least. Some say go according to your point of origin, others say use your converting rabbi's minhagim. There are also those opinions who offer methodologies to change your minhagim based upon familial approval. If one can change his existing minhagim, then choosing initial minhagim is certainly allowed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is a convert free to choose his own minhagim?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27820/is-a-convert-free-to-choose-his-own-minhagim)

Comment: @loewian, I suspect that the OP is asking in reference to R' Ovadia's p'sak

Comment: halokho is not bound by land except for the obvious laws of the land. follow the halokhoth that the sanhadhreen aleiham ha sholom had decreed. if you believe the teimonim hold the closest to what you think is original/authentic judaism you are free to do so

Comment: I think that, according to R. Ovadia Yosef, outside _Eretz Yisra'el_ he is to take the _Minhagim_ according to whoever the _Mara de-Atra_ is where he converted. Also, I think that whichever he takes, when he moves to another place, he'd have to take the _Minhagim_ according to the _Mara de-Atra_ of that place. (For instance, if he moved to _Eretz Yisra'el_, he'd have to take the _Minhagim_ of the Sepharadim.)

Comment: The reasoning appears a little circular to me. If I take Sephardi minhagim than I have to follow R' Ovadya who says I need to take Sephardi minhagim. But if I do not take Sephardi minhagim, then I do not need to follow R' Ovadya's psak...